# Laravel Elixir paths

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I use Elixir to compile my less files

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.less([
    "../../../vendor/uikit/uikit/src/less/uikit.less",
    "main.less"
], 'public/css/style.css').version("public/css/style.css");
});
```

then I try to use css file like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('css/style.css') }}">
```

but I result I get `http://localhost:8080/build/css/style-a3ade8736f.css 404 (Not Found)`

I use XAMMP so my url looks like `http://localhost:8080/ad/public/`

When I try to add 'piblic/' word in css href like
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/{{ elixir('css/style.css') }}">`
I get an error to like
    `http://localhost:8080/ad/public/public//build/css/style-a3ade8736f.css 404 (Not Found)`

How to fix href?

Answer (score 5):

You can call Elixir function inside `asset()` or `url()`.

Like this:

```
{{ asset(elixir('css/style.css')) }}
```

Or

```
{{ url(elixir('css/style.css')) }}
```

This [thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7304) solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Call the `elixir` function inside `asset()` or `URL::Asset()`

gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less').version('css/app.css');
});
```

Blade

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset( elixir('css/app.css') ) }}" charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `elixir` function expects you to [have versioned the file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting) by doing `version()` in your Gulpfile.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version("css/all.css");
});
```

Comment: Yep, and I have it in `/public/build/css/style-23b9bf0277.css` I just don't understand how to get right path.

Comment: @Heidel Check that `public/build/rev-manifest.json` is writeable and being updated. That's where the `elixir()` PHP function gets the hash to use.

Comment: Yep, it  is writeable and being updated too ) the problem is the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was pulling my hair out.  It appears the issue is a slightly misleading documentation on how the URL is called.  In the manual, it notes that a simple

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('output/all.css') }}">
```

should be all you need and it should automatically call the right script.  Unfortunately, depending on the server, it is possible the line above would call to an incorrect URL, as was the case on mine:

```
<script src="/build/output/all-45ca09b2ad.css"></script>
```

When what we need is

```
<script src="http://localhost/yourAlias/build/output/all-45ca09b2ad.css"></script>
```

I was able to resolve this issue by wrapping the call in an HTML style block like so

```
{!! HTML::style(elixir('output/final.css')) !!}
```

HTH

Comment: When I try this it errors out saying that Class HTML not found. Any ideas?

Comment: @Colin Stadig, Yes, the HTML helper framework was unfortunately left out of one of the Laravel versions (5.1?)  You can either call this via a standard <link> and put the elixir bit in {{}} within blade, or use the Collective dependency (which is outstanding btw and does Forms as well as the HTML stuff) by including:  "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",  in your composer 'require' block.